# What is the battle music for Ace vs Aokiji?

Tags: one-piece, music

I want to know what is battle music that plays during the Ace and Aokiji clash. Can anyone provide me a link to the OST?

Comment: For the uninformed, which episode are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the OST From Movie 7: Karakuri's Castle's Mecha Giant Soldier 
the Duel of Zoro VS General Maji.
Here's the YouTube Link:
[Movie 7 OST](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuN2RfKlyiw)